# Parse XML to extract data with grouping

Tags: python, xml, shell, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

Could you please assist me to extract the data from XML in a way that I would need.

**XML:**

```
<DATA>

<HITS>ABC
<REC>123456789</REC>
<PRIORITY>0</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>DEF
<REC>123456789</REC>
<PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>GHI
<REC>55555555555</REC>
<PRIORITY>-1</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>JKL
<REC>55555555555</REC>
<PRIORITY>-5</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>PKR 
<REC>55555555555</REC> 
<PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY> 
</HITS>

<HITS>MNO
<REC>999999999999</REC>
<PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>DXB
<REC>888888888888</REC>
<PRIORITY>-2</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

<HITS>JFK
<REC>888888888888</REC>
<PRIORITY>-1</PRIORITY>
</HITS>

</DATA>
```

I need to get the maximum priority in the XML grouped by REC along with HITS count, is it possible to get it done using awk, sed, grep, python script or shell script to make it work in AIX server?

For Example logic of my output should be something like this:

HITS ABC and DEF will be grouped into one unique REC (123456789), and the maximum priority is 1. (1 > 0)

Output Slab for the Hits (ABC, DEF) :

```
PRIORITY REC  HITS  
1        1    2
```

HITS GHI,JKL,PKR will be grouped into one unique REC (55555555555), and the maximum priority is 1. (1 > -1 > -5).

Output Slab for the Hits (GHI, JKL and PKR) :

```
PRIORITY REC  HITS  
1        1    3
```

HITS MNO is the only member of the group unique REC (999999999999) and it has priority 1.

Output Slab for the Hit (MNO) :

```
PRIORITY REC  HITS  
1        1    1
```

HITS DXB and JFK is grouped into unique REC (888888888888) and it has priority -1. (-1 > -2)

Output Slab for the Hit (DXB and JFK) :

```
PRIORITY REC  HITS  
-1       1    2
```

FINAL OUTPUT (Count of Unique Records (REC) are aggregated based on the values of priority):

```
PRIORITY REC  HITS  
1        3    6
-1       1    2
```

Please note: A Typical XML file is of huge size it is  likely more than 600 MB, so the shell script, awk, sed,python script, grep or shell script should be efficient to handle XML of huge file size.

Comment: I don't see any relation between the tags supplied and the question itself. Could you please inspect the tags you placed (every StackOverflow tag has a small wiki page stating when it shall be applied)? You can edit your own question post at any time.

Comment: Experts always advice to use tools which know how to parse xml, so I added xmlstarlet tag here.

Comment: Thanks for adding proper tags

Comment: "HITS MNO has only one REC and it has prioirty 1. " Then why is it group with ABC which has priority 0 and a different  REC? Your logic isn't clear.

Comment: @JackFleeting thanks for your comment. If you look at the XML closely, hits ABC and DEF falls into the same REC 123456789  and the maximum value of priority for this REC between these two hits would be 1.

Comment: That part I understand; but why is MNO grouped with the two of them and not on its own? It doesn't have the same REC as the other two, and only has the same priority as one of them. What if one of the items with REC "555.." also had priority 1; where would MNO belong then?

Comment: @JackFleeting  I am sorry my question was bit confusing earlier , edited my question to give some more clarity with slab outputs. Hit MNO is tagged to REC and the unique REC are aggregated at last. If other record "555.." has priority 1 then the count of unique records are added up in the final output.

Comment: Almost there: please edit your code to add `<HITS>PKR
<REC>55555555555</REC>
<PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
</HITS>` and show the new `FINAL OUTPUT`.

Comment: @JackFleeting Done Jack, added PKR hit details and also added couple of other HITS to have  another Priority row to the final result.

Comment: Not yet... Should Output Slab for the Hit (DXB and JFK),using your logic,  be

`PRIORITY REC  HITS  
-1       1    2`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes you are right. Apologize, It was a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211959/discussion-between-jack-fleeting-and-naga).

Comment: Usually easier to use DOM based tools (loading all data into memory). Given file size, is this realistic - or are you looking into a solution that will be "event-based" to avoid loading all data into memory ?

Comment: The sample data does not have start/end tags. Is the data wrapped inside a <DATA> </DATA> tags (or similar), or is a series of small XML documents ?

Comment: @dash-o yes loading into memory is realistic in my case since I would run the script in a server with massive memory capacity. Event-based approach might not work for this experiment.

Comment: @dash-o you are right, yes the data is wrapped inside another single parent tag, I did not include that in my question, we could assume it is wrapped into <DATA></DATA> tag.

Comment: @naga thanks for clarifying. I've posted a solution that uses little memory, using SAX parser. I'll appreciate if you can test it, and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP indicated that he would prefer to have the answer in Python, this is what I used here - lxml (with xpath) and pandas. The question has a fairly complicated logical setup, to the code is somewhat complicated as well.

It's pretty late here right now, so I'll post the answer, and try to explain it later:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

hitlist = """[your xml above]
doc = etree.fromstring(hitlist)

uniq_recs = []   
recs = doc.xpath('//rec')
for rec in recs:
    if not rec.text in uniq_recs:
        uniq_recs.append(rec.text)

hit_counts = []
max_priority = []
uniq_priorities = []

for u in uniq_recs:
    priorities = []
    hit_counts.append(int(doc.xpath(f'count(//hits[./rec/text()={u}])')))
    for rec in recs:    
        if rec.text==u:
            priorities.append(int(rec.xpath('..//priority/text()')[0]))

    max_priority.append(max(priorities))
    if max(priorities) not in uniq_priorities:
        uniq_priorities.append(max(priorities))

rows = []
for up in uniq_priorities: 
    row = []
    hitts= 0
    for p, h in zip(max_priority, hit_counts):
        if p==up:
            hitts+=h
    row.extend((up,max_priority.count(up),hitts))
    rows.append(row)

columns = ['PRIORITY', 'REC',  'HITS']
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    PRIORITY    REC     HITS
0         1     3       6
1       -1      1       2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jack Fleeting. I was able to make it work with little changes with actual sample XML. A small blocker though,  <HITS> tag count in final output is Zero when the REC has Key values like this F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FB9, i guess the script was not able to compare when it has a value like this.

Comment: I had one more error cropping up "xml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: PCDATA invalid Char value 2, line 23, column 19" since my xml has special characters like STX, is there a work around for this?

Comment: HITS count are precise in final output when the REC tag contains simpler values like 999999999999, 55555555555 etc, same thing does not work when REC tag checksum keys like  F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FB9

Comment: @Naga - Unfortunately, you didn't include these special cases in the xml in the question so I'm not sure what the problem is. I would just post it as a new question, since this one has been modified a lot.

Comment: I overlooked and thought CHEKSUM Keys will be treated same as the NUMBERS, is there way to tweak little bit to make it work?

Comment: @Naga I changed the `<REC>` numbers of `<HITS>` ABC and DEF to ` F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FB9` and it still works on my end, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Output from my end: C:\Users\lakshmanann\Desktop\ERF>python priority.py
['123456789', '55555555555', '999999999999', '888888888888']
   FPR  DKY  H
0    1    3  6
1   -1    1  2

C:\Users\lakshmanann\Desktop\ERF>python priority.py
['123456789', 'F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FBF', '55555555555', '999999999999', '888888888888']
   FPR  DKY  H
0    1    3  4
1   -1    2  2

Comment: @Naga I don't think we will able to resolve your specific problem without you posting the full, unedited, actual XML which is probably confidential.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that proper XML parsing is required, suggesting breaking the problem into few steps - python
* Converting each "HITS" XML entry into (python) dictionary
* Grouping the dictionaries by REC, finding max priority, count
* Grouping the RECS by priority, finding count(hits), count(recs)

Step 1 & 2 can be combined together, step #3 must be performed as separate pass (it's not clear from OP question if data is guaranteed to be sorted by REC).

For step #1, better to use SAX parser (event based) to avoid loading the whole dataset into memory.

I believe steps 2 & 3 can use have better implementation. I'm still in the process of transitioning to Python. Consider the implementation below as efficient starting point

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import xml.sax

debug = False

class recItem:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.count = 0
        self.maxPri = None


    # Dictionary by REC of recItem
recData = {}

class dataHandler (xml.sax.ContentHandler):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.lastTag = ""
        self.data = None

    def startElement(self, tag, attribute):
        if ( debug ):
            print "S", self, tag, attribute
        self.lastTag = tag
        if tag == "HITS":
            self.data = { "HITS": "", "REC": "", "PRIORITY": "" }

    def characters(self, content):
        if ( debug ):
            print "C", self, self.lastTag, content
        if ( self.data != None and self.lastTag in self.data ):
            self.data[self.lastTag] += content

   def endElement(self, tag):
        if ( debug ):
            print "E", self, tag
        self.lastTag = None
        if ( tag == "HITS" ) :

            rec = self.data["REC"]
            priority = int(self.data["PRIORITY"])
            hits = self.data["HITS"]

            # Find priority by rec
            if ( rec in recData ):
                # Find max priority
                if ( priority > recData[rec].maxPri ):
                    recData[rec].maxPri = priority
            else:
                # New REC
                item = recItem();
                item.maxPri = priority ;
                recData[rec] = item
            recData[rec].count += 1

            self.data = None

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)
parser.setContentHandler(dataHandler())
parser.parse("data.xml")

if ( debug ):
    for k, v in recData.items():
        print k, v.maxPri, v.count
```

Step #3

```
class priItem:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.hits = 0
        self.recs = 0

# Group REC by priority
priData = {}
for k, v in recData.items():
    priEntry = priData[v.maxPri] if v.maxPri in priData else None
    if ( priEntry == None ):
        priEntry = priData[v.maxPri] = priItem()
    priEntry.hits += v.count
    priEntry.recs += 1
# Print final output
print "PRIORITY", "REC", "HITS"
for k, v in priData.items():
    print k, v.recs, v.hits
```

Output (matches OP request), can be formatted to CSV, or similar, if needed.

```
PRIORITY REC HITS
1 3 6
-1 1 2
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question, I am not able to run the script, could you please guide on how to run it? It throws many indent errors.

Comment: I am testing it in windows machine for now.

Comment: @Naga, I''m interested in feedback, especially about performance, if you can share.

Comment: Sure, I am taking two approaches for solving this problem with performance using python or powershell , should have results by this week. Will share it once I have it

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. I do not know if this solution will keep up with an input of 600Mb, too.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

dic = {}
tmp = {}
def setData(html):
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
  # First, get all data, group
  for hits in doc.HITSs:
    rec = hits.REC.text
    if not tmp.get(rec):
      tmp[rec] = []
    tmp.get(rec).append({'hits':hits.firstText(),'priority':int(hits.PRIORITY.text)})

with open('data.xml', 'r') as file: # data.xml is your xml file path
  lines = []
  flag = False
  for line in file:
    if flag or line.find('<HITS>')>=0:
      flag = True
      lines.append(line)
    if line.find('</HITS>')>=0:
      setData("".join(lines))
      flag = False
      lines = []
# Sort, get maximum
for rec in tmp:
  values = tmp.get(rec)
  values.sort(key=lambda hits: hits.get('priority'),reverse=True)
  priority = values[0].get('priority')
  # PRIORITY, HITS
  if dic.get(priority) is None:
    dic[priority]=[0,0]
  arr = dic.get(priority)
  arr[0] = arr[0]+1
  arr[1] = arr[1]+len(values)
# Result
for i in dic:
  arr = dic.get(i)
  print (i,arr[0],arr[1])
```

Result:

```
1 3 6
-1 1 2
```

Comment: perfect, it worked and yielded the results that I wanted. however the process to extract the data is pretty slow.

Comment: I just modified with open('data.xml', 'r') to with open('data.xml', 'r', encoding="utf8")

Comment: @Naga 600MB, the amount of data is really a bit large. If you will execute it repeatedly, you can extract it and put it in the database, and then operate on the database, which should be much faster.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot push it to DB easily due to process restrictions and can't control the XML sizing.

Comment: however we are pushing it to DB to get the stats as we don't have other option yet, it is taking longer time and we can't play with XML to make it to load into DB faster, else the dependent process wont accept the data, the only option we have is to cut down the time down with the script.

Comment: Yes, if it's only a one-time statistics, it can also be received a little longer:)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/<DATA>//g; s/<\/HITS>/#/g; s/<[/A-Z]*>/ /g' xml.xml |
        awk '!/#/{ s=s $0 }/#/{ print s; s="" }' |
        awk '{ p[$2]++; if(m[$2]<=$3) m[$2]=$3; else m[$2]=$3; }
            END{ print "PRIORITY REC HITS";
                 for(i in p) { print  m[i],1,p[i]; y[m[i]]=m[i]; x[m[i]]=x[m[i]]+p[i]; z[m[i]]++ };
                 print "FINAL";
                 for (i in y) { print i, z[y[i]], x[y[i]] } }'
```

1. sed will 'flatten' the xml-file  (which i named: `xml.xml`)
2. awk will do the last piece of 'flattening'....
3. awk will count the number of occurrences, and determine the max

output after step 2, the 'flattend' file:

```
 ABC 123456789  0
 DEF 123456789  1
 GHI 55555555555  -1
 JKL 55555555555  -5
 PKR  55555555555   1
 MNO 999999999999  1
 DXB 888888888888  -2
 JFK 888888888888  -1
```

output at the end:

```
PRIORITY REC HITS
1 1 1
-1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 2
FINAL
-1 1 2
1 3 6
```

I do not know if this solution will keep up with an input of 600Mb....